# How can I make the text vertical align in UILabel of Xib file in iOS 7

Tags: text, ios7, uilabel, center

The label I need is an IBOutlet.

I have set mini font size, 1 lines, and baselineAdjustment to UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters, but the text still not align vertically.

It works in iOS 6 Simulator, but not work in iOS 7.

Comment: can you add some code from your effort

Comment: try with this [myLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [myLabel sizeToFit];

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have worked it out, just change the Line Breaks (in interface builder) to Truncate Tail, and the text vertical align in iOS 7.

Comment: that doesn't work if the text doesn't fit into 1 line. Then it will just "truncate tail" (as you set it), and not break the text onto the next line.